# Should FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() be used sparingly?

Tags: android, optimization, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example when I use a SQLiteDatabase in android, it is generally not a good idea to open/close lots of SQLiteDatabase helpers. Instead it is better to create a sort of singleton which makes sure you only have 1 database open.

Say I have a class with static methods doing lots of Firebase operations which require a DatabaseReference.
example:

```
static void checkIfUserIsMatched(...)
static void notifyUser(...)
static void modifyUser(...)
```

Is it OK to call FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() inside every method? Create a new DatabaseReference inside each method?

or would it be better to pass the DatabaseReference from the calling Activity?

```
static void notifyUser(mUserReference, hisUserId)
```

vs

```
static void notifyUser(myUserId, hisUserId) --> Create the reference inside method
```

What im looking to optimize is network usage and performance. Or does this all not matter and does firebase handle everything for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`FirebaseDatabase` and `DatabaseReference` objects can be considered relatively cheap references to the underlying resources.

The Firebase SDK manages such things behind the scenes. Only the first call to `FirebaseData.getInstance()` will do the set up work, subsequent calls (within the same process) will simply re-use what was done already.