# Does Initializing FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() Multiple Times Affect Performance?

Tags: java, android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When developing Android Apps using Firebase, we would do something like this to read from or write to Firebase Realtime Database:

```
Line 1: FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
Line 2: DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("A").child("B").child("C");
Line 3: myRef.setValue(50);
```

In the above example, we are writing '50' into the location of "A/B/C", but if, after the previous write operation, I then want to write to another location (let's say "A/D/E"), is it a good practice performance-wise to write Line 1~3 again in another place under the same file (See 'Approach 1' below), or should I just write Line 2~3, since "FirebaseDatabase database" has already been declared in Line 1 (See 'Approach 2' below)?

**Approach 1:**

```
Line 1: FirebaseDatabase database1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
Line 2: DatabaseReference myRef1 = database1.getReference("A").child("B").child("C");
Line 3: myRef1.setValue(50);
...
Line 4: FirebaseDatabase database2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
Line 5: DatabaseReference myRef2 = database2.getReference("A").child("D").child("E");
Line 6: myRef2.setValue(60);
```

**Approach 2:**

```
Line 1: FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
Line 2: DatabaseReference myRef1 = database.getReference("A").child("B").child("C");
Line 3: myRef1.setValue(50);
...
Line 4: DatabaseReference myRef2 = database.getReference("A").child("D").child("E");
Line 5: myRef2.setValue(60);
```

My question is, which one of the above approaches will result in better performance? Does creating FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() many times for every write operation improve performance (thus Approach 1 is better)? or does it make the performance worse (thus Approach 2 is better)?

Thanks!

Comment: Calling comprehensive methods on the main thread will slow down the app. If you are on the main thread, approach 2 is the best. Approach 2 is the best iether way, but if you use async threads, approach one can be done, but 2 is still the best and fastest. But approach 1 has most effect on performance if it is on the main thread

Comment: @LunarWatcher setValues return Task aka they do work asynchronously anyway. Also `getInstance()` returns the same instance so the both Approaches are the same

Comment: What if in both Approaches, instead of doing 2 writes, there are one read and one write (The read operation is going to be continuously working whenever values are changed in Firebase, as in myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot))?

Comment: I think both approach is the same whether its read or write operation, because `getInstace()` is really cheap (or even cost-less) as it only call already created static object. The difference, I think, will only be observable if you compare: (1) creating one `DatabaseReference` object and using it multiple time and (2) creating it every time you need it. Which of course the (1) will be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39109665/4810277).  Only the first `getInstance()` does real work. After that there is no performance gain/lose if you `getInstance()` everytime or reuse the same instance. Firebase will optimize the work in the background.